# Where does ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy get the .each instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have models Topics and Posts, where a Topic has_many :posts and a Post belongs_to :topic. I already have some stuff in my database at this point.

If I go into the rails console and type

```
Topic.find(1).posts
```

I believe I get back a CollectionProxy object.

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Post id:30, ......>]>
```

I can call .each on this to get an Enumerator object.

```
=> #<Enumerator: [#<Post id: 30, ......>]:each>
```

I'm confused as to how CollectionProxy is handling .each. I realize that it's inherited at some point but I've been reading the API docs and they don't make it very clear what CollectionProxy is inheriting from unless I'm missing something obvious.

[This page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) doesn't seem to tell me much, and neither does [this page](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` [is inherited from `Relation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cc60b5e3596d7763fa1c48fa12fee8dbba9a1a17/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L30), and `Relation` forwards `each` and many other methods to `to_a`.

From [activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L45](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cc60b5e3596d7763fa1c48fa12fee8dbba9a1a17/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L45)

> delegate :to_xml, :to_yaml, :length, :collect, :map, :each, :all?, :include?, :to_ary, :join, to: :to_a

See [Understanding Ruby and Rails: Delegate](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/) for an excellent explanation on how `delegate` works.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you try asking it where it comes from?

```
> ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.instance_method(:each).owner
=> ActiveRecord::Delegation
```

The [`UnboundMethod#owner`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-owner) method:

> Returns the class or module that defines the method.

so `each` comes from `ActiveRecord::Delegation`. And if you look at `ActiveRecord::Delegation`, [you'll see this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L46):

```
delegate ..., :each, ... , to: :to_a
```

so `each` is further punted to `to_a.each`.